# Laravel 4 - Modify a value in a Session Object

Tags: php, arrays, session, object, laravel-4

I have a session with name USER and i put object values to that session. If print that session, its will show result like below :

```
/* Print_r for Session::get('USER') */
    stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [session] => HpetWZYPY87PSf9pqx1AnCaMu89vHv
        [fullname] => Fredy
        [avatar] => 
        [dob] => 1992-01-19
        [gender] => L
        [register_date] => 2015-03-04 13:29:54
    )
```

If i return `Session::get('USER')->fullname` it will show `Fredy`.

My problem, how to change `Session::get('USER')->fullname` value from `Fredy` to `Alfred`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user = Session::get('user');
$user->fullname = "Fredy";
User->save($user); //if you need to update user on database
Session::put("user", $user);
```